# Synchronized batchnorm in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does distributed training with keras batchnorm in tensorflow 2 performs synchronized batchnorm between GPUs? If not is there a plan to add it?

Comment: Tensorflow/Keras feature questions are best asked in the respective mailing lists or github so that the developers can respond directly.